# No me carga datos en input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que por medio de un script jalo la info de la base de datos y esta se visualiza en cada input, les dejo una imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar todos los datos se reflejan menos el del usuario, no se si se debe al warning que me esta saliendo en la consola .

Como pueden ver el json esta pasando todos los datos al javascript.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mirando lo que se le esta asignando el input puedo ver que se le pasa el valor pero no lo esta mostrando.

Les dejo el codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar con este error.

```js
$(function(){
 $.post("../php/llenar.php", function(data){
  $("#capitan").html(data);
 });
 $.post("../php/tipo_user.php", function(data){
  $("#tpuser").html(data);
 });
 $.post("../php/llenar1.php", function(data){
  $("#congregacion").html(data);
 });
 $("#capitan").change(function(){
  $.get("../php/modificar.php",{cedula: $("#capitan").val()},function(data){
   $("input").removeAttr('disabled');
   $("select").removeAttr('disabled');
   $("#cedula").prop('disabled', true);
   $("#cedula").val(data.cedula);
   $("#nombre").val(data.nombre);
   $("#apellido").val(data.apellido);
   $("#mail").val(data.correo);
   $("#usuario").val(data.user);
   $("#pwd").val(data.pass);
   $("#congregacion").val(data.congregacion);
  },"json");
 });
 });
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 font: normal 18px/3 "Fira Sans", "Heveltica Neue", sans-serif;
 background: #3aafab;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
}

.form-registro{
 width: 95%;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 background:white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 
}
h2.titulo{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}
h2{
 background: deepskyblue;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top-left-radius: 7px;
 border-top-right-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid crimson;
}

.contenedor-input{
 padding: 10px 30px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

input{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.input-48{
 width: 48%;
}

.input-100{
 width: 100%;
}

select
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid darkgrey;
}

.btn-enviar{
 background: crimson;
 color: white;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-enviar:active{
 transform: scale(1.05);
}
.contenido{
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display:grid;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title id="usuario"></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/alertas.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/modificar_Cap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
  <h2> Modificar capitanes</h2>
  <div class ="contenedor-input">
   <select name = "capitan" id = "capitan" class = "input-100">
   </select>
   <input type = "text" id = "cedula" name = "cedula" placeholder = "Cedula" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "nombre"  name = "nombre" placeholder = "Nombres" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "apellido" name = "apellido" placeholder = "Apellidos" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "email" id = "mail" name = "mail" placeholder = "Correo electronico" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "usuario" name = "usua" placeholder = "Usuario" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <input type = "text" id = "pwd" name = "pwd" placeholder = "Contraseña" class = "input-48" disabled = false/>
   <select type = "text" id="congregacion" name = "congregacion" placeholder = "Congregacion" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   </select>
   <select type = "text" id="tpuser" name = "tpuser" placeholder = "Tipo de usuario" class = "input-100" disabled = false/>
   </select>
   <input type = "button" value = " Modificar capitan" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar"/>
 
  </div>  
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el PHP

```html
<?php
 include("conex.php");
 $cedula = $_GET['cedula'];
 $sql = "SELECT nombre_hermano, apellido_hermano, correo, user, pass, nombre_congregacion, descripcion FROM hermanos,congregacion, tipo_usuario WHERE cedula = '$cedula' AND congregacion.id_congregacion = hermanos.id_congregacion AND tipo_usuario.id_tipo = hermanos.id_tipo";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo json_encode(array("cedula"=>$cedula,"nombre"=>$row['nombre_hermano'], "apellido" =>$row['apellido_hermano'], "correo"=>$row['correo'], "user"=>$row['user'], "pass"=>$row['pass'], "congregacion"=>$row['nombre_congregacion'], "descripcion"=>$row['descripcion']));
?>
```

Agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: El problema seguramente es que tienes repetido en el código el id="usuario", en el title y en el input que quieres rellenar, y el id debe ser único. Prueba a cambiar el id del títle.

Comment: Gracias Carmen no me habia fijado en ese pequeño error, gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la declaración del title.

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title id="usuario"></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
    <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "../js/alertas.js"></script>
    <script src = "../js/modificar_Cap.js"></script>
</head>
```

Como ves el title tiene la id usuario y te esta asignando el user a ese titulo antes que al input, por eso no se ve. Quítale la id al title o cambiaselo por otro.

Comment: No me habia fijado en ese pequeño error, gracias por tu ayuda